# Proof that $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ is $O(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

My homework assignment is to proof that $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ is $O(\frac{1}{x})$.

I've seen different definitions of Big-Oh, but in my book it is defined as $|f(x)| \leq M \cdot|g(x)|$ for all $x \geq N$ (usually I don't see Big-Oh defined having absolute values for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$).

Now, I could come up with a table of values, but of course that doesn't proof anything. Could I proof it by doing this (I saw it somewhere searching for anwers)?
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}}{ \frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt{0}=0.
$$

Because the limit exists, have I proven that $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ is $O(\frac{1}{x})$? How come this works? It looks a whole lot like the limit comparison test. Are there any other ideas which could help me figure out if $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ is $O(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: By definition you wish to prove that $$\exists N\in \mathbb R\exists M\in \mathbb R^+\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(x\ge N\implies \left|\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt x}\right|\leq M\left|\dfrac{1}{x}\right|\right).$$ Suppose you have such $M,N$ just to see if that gives any clue as to what they may be. Assume that $x\ge N>0$. It follows that $$\left|\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt x}\right|\leq M\left|\dfrac{1}{x}\right|$$ or equivalently $$\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}\right|\leq M.$$ Now it's easy to find $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that there exists $N>0$ such that $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{x}$$ for every $x>N$. Just take $\epsilon=1$ in the definitin of limit. By the way, you proved much more, namely that $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} = o \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: If I read your first sentences correctly, $N$ could be any positive number, and this is what the limit means then? That it's the number from which one function will be bigger than the other one.
 
"Just take ϵ=1 in the definitin of limit" I assume that what you mean by this is that I could just simply take 1 as my $M$?

Comment: No, $N$ is given by the choice of $\epsilon=1$. It is the "$\delta$" in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and accepting of the answer. I had to brush up on the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits (I always had a hard time understanding that one) to figure out what you were saying.